# Mysql order by gives unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am getting a unexpected order of results when I run this mysql query

```
SELECT 
    score.field_score_value AS field_score_value
FROM node n 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_game game ON n.nid = game.entity_id 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_score score ON n.nid = score.entity_id 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_student student ON n.nid = student.entity_id 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_first_name name ON student.field_student_target_id = name.entity_id 
INNER JOIN field_data_field_last_name last ON student.field_student_target_id = last.entity_id 
INNER JOIN student_level level ON student.field_student_target_id = level.uid 
WHERE (game.field_game_target_id = 910) 
AND (level.group_level = 'intermediate')
ORDER BY score.field_score_value ASC
```

Here's my result

```
10
11
14
4
```

Why is ORDER BY score.field_score_value ASC not working?

Comment: Looks like its a varchar field so you need to convert to int in order by `order by cast(score.field_score_value as unsigned)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because its a string value and that's a natural order for that. You can force it to be treated as a number

```
ORDER BY CAST(score.field_score_value AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

P.S: Why have score as a `varchar` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `score.field_score_value` is defined as varchar.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is varchar type.you can use:

```
 ORDER BY convert(score.field_score_value, decimal) ASC
```

or

```
ORDER BY CAST(score.field_score_value as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC
```

**note:** but it will be better if you change in you database from varchar to int/bigint.